# PHP ignores "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: php, c++, apache, http-headers

My executable (C++ compiled with Visual Studio) communicates with the PHP webserver to submit data via POST. It worked as designed for years but suddenly stopped working correctly in January 2023. The only change which may happen is an upgrade of the webserver to PHP-8, and a regular Windows update, which changed WININET.DLL used by executable to send HTTP requests.

I am using the code like this (with my variables appropriately defined):

```
HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen( “lpszAgent”, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect( hSession, “server.XXX.com”, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

LPCSTR FAR* rgpszAcceptTypes = { _T("*/*"), NULL };
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest( hConnect, "POST",  “path_to_script.php”, NULL, NULL, rgpszAcceptTypes, 0, NULL);

LPCSTR lpszHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
DWORD dwHeadersLength = strlen(lpszHeaders);
LPCSTR pfrmdata = "a=b&etc";//correctly encoded
DWORD dwOptionalLength = strlen(pfrmdata);

bool ok = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, lpszHeaders, dwHeadersLength, (void*)pfrmdata, dwOptionalLength);
```

Everything works without any errors. However, on the server side, I get an empty POST and the following headers:

```
SERVER:
array (
  'LSPHP_ENABLE_USER_INI' => 'on',
  'PATH' => '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin',
  'TEMP' => '/tmp',
  'TMP' => '/tmp',
  'TMPDIR' => '/tmp',
  'PWD' => '/',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => '*/*',
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'Keep-Alive',
  'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '0',
  'HTTP_HOST' => ‘Correct ',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Correct',
  'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'no-cache',
  'REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID' => 'Y82i1YUhgzjQfeXqYUTbfQAAAH8',
  'REDIRECT_QS_SrvConn' => '70',
  'REDIRECT_QS_AllConn' => '75',
  'REDIRECT_QS_ConnectionId' => '167442094953986927446367',
  'REDIRECT_HTTPS' => 'on',
  'REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI' => 'Correct',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',
  'UNIQUE_ID' => 'Y82i1YUhgzjQfeXqYUTbfQAAAH8',
  'QS_SrvConn' => '70',
  'QS_AllConn' => '75',
  'QS_ConnectionId' => '167442094953986927446367',
  'HTTPS' => 'on',
  'SSL_TLS_SNI' => 'Correct',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache',
  'SERVER_NAME' => 'Correct ',
  'SERVER_ADDR' => 'Correct',
  'SERVER_PORT' => '443',
  'REMOTE_ADDR' => 'Correct',
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => 'Correct',
  'REQUEST_SCHEME' => 'https',
  'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => '',
  'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => 'Correct',
  'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'Correct',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => 'Correct',
  'REMOTE_PORT' => '8700',
  'REDIRECT_URL' => 'Correct',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'QUERY_STRING' => '',
  'REQUEST_URI' => 'Correct',
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => 'Correct',
  'PHP_SELF' => 'Correct',
  'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1674420950.062037944793701171875,
  'REQUEST_TIME' => 1674420950,
  'argv' => 
  array (
  ),
  'argc' => 0,
)
```

As you may see CONTENT_LENGTH=0 and CONTENT_TYPE is absent at all, while it should be “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”, and REQUEST_METHOD is GET instead of POST.

I understand that CONTENT_TYPE is essential. If it is not there then POST data is not read,  REQUEST_METHOD becomes GET, and CONTENT_LENGTH becomes zero and my data submitted consequently ignored by the server.

So, the problem is that CONTENT_TYPE has disappeared from the request. But why? What is wrong now? Please, recall that it used to all work just fine before January 2023.

I tried to downgrade PHP to 7.4 - it did not help.

I put my script on a different server under a site which uses PHP 7.4 - it started working!

I made a new test site on the other server with the latest PHP 8.2 - it does not work.
Downgraded PHP 8.2 to PHP 7.4 - still did not help.

I installed a new test site on other server and set PHP 7.4 during the installation - it now works!
I upgaded it to PHP 8.2 - stopped working.
I downgraded back to PHP 7.4 - still does not work.

Could this have been more confusing? I beg you to give me some ideas. Thank you!

---

Update:
Thank you so much for all the comments. Indeed, it must be a redirection of HTTP to HTTPS at fault. The hosting provider (Hostmonster) has recently installed free SSL certificates to all the domains and made all domains use HTTPS. They think they have done a great job and refuse to understand my problem. My executable still works via HTTP, and the redirection breaks it. I am failing to explain to them what I need at the level of support I get from them. They think it all works great and advise me to hire a developer :) They do not seem to provide an option to stop redirection.

I think, I should be able to disable their server-wide redirection from the local .htaccess file. But I am not sure how to do that. I guess, I need to see which method they used to enable it, but I could not figure out how to see the Apache configuration for my domain/location on a shared server.

Could you guess which lines in the local .htaccess would possibly disable the automatic redirection from HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like Wireshark to inspect the actual request sent?

Comment: The shown dump of the headers definitively is not of the shown request. `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT` (80) is set to the request. `'HTTPS' => 'on',  'SERVER_PORT' => '443'` is in the dump.

Comment: If it's a correct dump, then the port 80 is redirected by Apache or PHP to the port 443 with the code 302 that mandates changing POST request to GET.

Comment: Your `'REQUEST_METHOD'` is `'GET'` while sending `POST` that means it was redirected some where. Look into your .htaccess and check if there is any redirect from non HTTPS or not.